# Create custom fields as image uploads

Tags: wp-admin, custom-field, customization, uploads, images

How can I define a custom field that works as an image upload? Should be fairly basic but I can't seem to find the solution.

Let's say you create the post type 'book' and want to create 3 fields: cover, back, index... I don't know...

I've done similar stuff in the past with flutter/magic fields but they don't seem to be updated or support native WP3 custom post types.

Alternatives anyone? Thanks in advance

Comment: interested in this question as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Multiple Post Thumbnails plugin, http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multiple-post-thumbnails/.  It will allow you to set a post type to have more than one post thumbnail, so you can set a front, back, index separately using the built-in handling.

Comment: That's what I was using. Is not exactly what I want. I want a more custom-cms-like kind of field but I guess this will have to do it for now :S